# Rounded UITableView with thin edges like FaceTime app

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

How i can create tableview like this?

[image]

(separators merges with edges and edges is rounded)

Comment: You need grouped UITableView, and it looks this way in iOS versions below iOS 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was out of the box in system version below 7.0. If you want something similar, you can make custom graphic for the first and last cell. In UITableViewDataSource you have got a method, which helps you to control cell's content.

> - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

From indexPath.row you can get cell number to know if it is first or last cell in the section. And you can set your custom cell look.

Comment: Thank for answer! I understand that I need do something like that, but I don't know how to draw cells programmatically.

Comment: check out the trail of this ... will give you plenty of clues. http://www.paintcodeapp.com

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add UITextfields without background [UIColor clearColor] and put a background image to your login cell

Comment: Thank for answer! I have a lot of tables and the number of rows dynamically changes. I think the use of image it is not best way.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use table view with rounded corner you should go with QuartzCore framework by importing

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

then

in your method from where you create table view use following code -

```
yourTableView.layer.masksToBounds = TRUE;
yourTableView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f; // as per you requirement please give this value.
```

you can take any number of rows. but table corners remains as it is.
I think this will help you....